# Show boolean values as icons

Tags: jsf

I have DataTable with 5 columns. In one column are boolean values – true or false. I would like to show icons instead “true” or “false” literals. How can I show Boolean values as icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is quiet simple.You just use the **rendered** attribute. Try this code:

```
<h:column> 
   <f:facet name="header">Col Name</f:facet> 
     <h:graphicImage value="../image1.jpg" rendered="#{yourBoolean}" /> 
     <h:graphicImage value="../image2.jpg" rendered="#{!yourBoolean}" /> 
</h:column>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by using `rendered`'s attribute of the graphic image's tag :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{managedBean.yourList}" var="list" rules="all" >    
    <h:column>
    ...
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">Your column name</f:facet>
          <h:graphicImage rendered="#{list.yourBoolean eq true}" library="images/SomeFolder" name="someTrueImage.png" />
          <h:graphicImage rendered="#{list.yourBoolean eq false}" library="images/SomeFolder" name="someFalseImage.png" />
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
    ...
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rendered` attribute (as you can see in other answers), or incorporate condition inside `value` tag using ternary operator:

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{yourBoolean ? image1.png : image2.png}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

The best (IMO) would be :

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.myList}" var="myVarName">
```

.
..
...

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{myVarName.myBoolean?'myTrueClass':'myFalseClass'}"/>
```

where in css

```
.myTrueClass {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image:url('../resources/images/myTrue.png');
}

.myFalseClass {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image:url('../resources/images/myFalse.png');
}
```

By using the css you will make you life much easier... easier to maintain